# opened port on router for java socket

Tags: firewall, port, peer-to-peer

I am trying to make a peer to peer application and I want a port to exchange connection information and I want to ensure that this port would not be closed from the firewall on the way between peers and this port is not used by another application

Comment: 1. Try to open it with UPNP. 2. The Firewall doesn't close any ports if it's not told to do so. (And if it's told to do so, it should happen, doesn't matter if you want it to happen or not) 3. You should not prevent any application from  using the port.

Comment: It's not clear, but if you're developing an application you'll probably get more useful answers if you take this question to http://stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there are several ways to establish a connection between peers that cannot accept incoming connections at their apparent Internet addresses.

- Determine if there appears to be network address translation (NAT), and if there is, attempt to use UPnP and/or other NAT port mapping protocols to configure any NAT routers that respond to forward a port at the Internet address to the local address
- If one of the peers can accept incoming connections, coordinate so that it listens for a connection and the other peer connects to it
- Use NAT traversal techniques to attempt to establish a connection https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal